# How to get the last object [".Z3ebra_tip2"] orhow to write it in simple oneline code

Tags: jquery

```
$('.agreechk').append($('.zebra_tips2').attr('cdata'));
$('.zebra_tips2').removeAttr("cdata");
```

Is there any other option for get it as simple one line code to remove the attribute from ".zebra_tips2 " using end() or other jquery function?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: whats wrong with the current code?

Comment: I need it like $('.agreechk').append($('.zebra_tips2').attr('cdata')).('.zebra_tips2').removeAttr("cdata");[not correct ]